# How do I delete an message in Discord.js?

Tags: discord

Hi I want to delete a message in Discord.js v12. How do I do that?
I have tried this

```js
message.content.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: message.delete()

Ex:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'sb',
    aliases: [],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.delete()

            message.channel.send(`teest`)
                .then(msg => {
                    setInterval(function() {
                        msg.edit(`test!`)
                    }, 3000);
                })
        }
}
```